# skunk deterrent using dish detergent

Tags: lawn-repair

I have skunks digging up my lawn.  One solution indicates spray 1C castor oil, mixed with 1C dish detergent in a gallon of water.  Would that concentration kill the grass especially since it is mixed with another solution (castor oil)

Thanks

Comment: If '1C' refers to 1 cupful, how big is the cup?

Comment: @Bamboo As OP says "gallon", I'd estimate 1cup = 245ml. I guess we are talking US units again.

Comment: In US measurements, 1 cup is equal to 8 fluid ounces and 1 gallon is 16 cups or 128 fl. oz.

Comment: If skunks are hungry they will ignore this.  You likely have chafer or Japanese beetle grubs in the lawn.

Answer (score 2):

Crikey, I've thrown away my old jug with fluid ounces marked on it, everything I possess for measuring liquids is in litres.... but it seems as if what you're proposing means there will be just over 7 parts water to castor oil and washing up liquid combined, assuming you mean, by gallon, the American liquid gallon. I'm not sure what effect it will have on the grass, but people do use these sorts of combinations on lawns for attempting to prevent mole invasions, so I imagine it can't do much harm. I wouldn't recommend applying it regularly though, but a one off is probably fine. I guess you could do a test patch, but you'd have to leave it a few months to see what happened over time.